# Fluent validation remove comma from description

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I am using fluent validation library which is class cant believe its given away for free. But I am having an issue I need to pre validate a file before hand and tell them to correct the error in the third party program and export again.

One of the critatea must be that a comma is not contained in the description is their a simple way of doing this. Now I know what you are going to say, 
 "just replace the comma", but the data is coming from another source and we wish them to correct that data first.

```
public class FluentStockValidator : AbstractValidator<StockImportCsv>
{
    public FluentStockValidator()
    {


        RuleFor(x => x.Itemcode).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Item Code must not  be empty.");
        RuleFor(x => x.Itemcode).Length(1,30).WithMessage("Item Code must been between 1 and 30 chars long.");

        RuleFor(x => x.Barcode).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Barcode must not be empty.");
        RuleFor(x => x.description).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Description is required");

        RuleFor(x => x.Itemcode).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Item Code cannot be blank");
    }
}
```

Comment: `RuleFor(x => x.description).Must(x => !x.Contains(",")).WithMessage("Item Description must not contain a comma");`

Comment: @linuxrocks Thanks linuxrocks this is indeed the answer but as you did not supply an answer can only give a mention here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
        RuleFor(m => m.Description).NotEmpty().Must(x => !x.Contains(",")).WithMessage(YOURMESSAGE);
```

or

```
        RuleFor(m => m.Description).NotEmpty().Matches("^[^,]+$").WithMessage(YOURMESSAGE);
```

Note that `Must` only work on the server side, so if you have client side validation enabled, and `Description` has a comma, it will pass the client side validation. Matches does work on both server and client according to the [docs](https://fluentvalidation.net/aspnet#asp-net-mvc-5)